# A question regarding probability density functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

If the probability density function $f$ of some continuous random variable $X$ is defined as it is below, will $E[X] = 0$ for all $X$? $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are finite but arbitrary.

$$f(x) = \cases{g(x)\text{,} \enspace x\in(\alpha, \beta) \\ 0\text{,} \enspace x \notin(\alpha, \beta)}$$

Comment: Where does this obviously false statement at stake come from?

Comment: The expected value would be $\displaystyle\int_\alpha^\beta x \ g(x)\ \text dx$. There is no reason to think that this would necessarily be zero...

Comment: David: Why leave @zoli's *quite natural* query, unanswered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

*For example*, take
$$f(x) = \cases{2x\text{,} \enspace x\in(0, 1) \\\\ 0\text{,} \enspace x \notin(0, 1)}$$ we have
$$
E(X)=\int_0^1x \cdot 2x \: dx=\left[ \frac23\cdot x^3\right]_0^1=\frac23 \neq 0.
$$

Comment: @David You are welcome.